# Select library column

Tags: python, r, analysis

I have a dataset in which one of the columns contains a library of different 'subcolumns'. For data preparation purposes, I want to extract certain parts of that column and store it into a new column. The data looks like this:

[image: ss of image 1]

I'm looking to get a new, third, column that contains a header that says 'animal' and contains rows that say 'dog' and 'cat'. Like this:

[image: ss of image 2]

I usually work with [r](/questions/tagged/r), and the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) library seems the right solution, but no success so far. I'm also familiar with [python](/questions/tagged/python) by the way. Anyone that can be of help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search SO for answers in your preferred language dealing with key:value pairs. The close votes probably relate to the lack of a [MCVE] in a for that can be converted to code easily. There is great annoyance on SO when data is presented as a picture. It implies that you think we should redo _your_ data entry.

Comment: Hi Michiel. Could you please post your original data frame (or a subset of it) using `dput` to make this a minimally reproducible example? The solution will depend quite a bit on exactly how that input data is formatted and escaped. thanks :)